# В каких случаях внутренние группировки нужны в подзапросах?

Tags: sql, производительность, group-by

В каких случаях внутренние группировки нужны в подзапросах? Ведь если результаты передаются "вверх", где в конечном итоге группируются, то внутренние получается не нужны. Например:

```
SELECT n1.field1, n1.field2 ...
  FROM (SELECT field1, field2 ...
          FROM ...
         GROUP BY field1, field2 ...) n1
GROUP n1.field1, n1.field, ...
```

Внутренняя группировка `GROUP BY field1, field2` не нужна, т.к. всё равно эта операция происходит в конце `GROUP n1.field1, n1.field, ...` Т.е. получается всегда надо только делать в конце группировку или есть случаи когда внутренняя необходима?

P.S. Подзапросы могут быть разные, через `WHERE`, через `FROM` или через `JOIN` или через `WITH`

Comment: Я не знаю структуру вашей БД, сложно сказать, точно ли необходимы группировки в подзапросах или можно обойтись как то без них. Но есть случаи, когда без группировки обойтись сложно. Например, когда вы используете функции агрегирования к сгруппированным данным подзапроса: MIN(), MAX(), SUM(), AVG() и COUNT(). Даже к одной таблице, например, вывести всех учеников с оценкой в баллах выше среднего балла. Или даже так: вывести средний балл оценок по химии только учеников, которые получали оценку выше средней оценки по математике.

Comment: Вы очень правильно указали тег 'производительность' ... представьте что вам надо сделать join еще с одной таблицей, по полю field1 а в вашей первой таблице миллионы записей, которые группируются до нескольких тысяч. можно сначала сделать join а потом group by, но тогда join будет выполнен миллионы раз, а потом этот большой набор еще группировать и это может длиться часами. А если сначала сделать в подзапросе group by, а потом выполнить join, то группировать меньший объем и join делать всего несколько тысяч раз, что вполне способно в сотни раз ускорить запрос

Comment: Это был пример на производительность. А примеров когда логика построения результата требует второй группировки в обертке (а бывает и 5-10 уровней вложенности запросов) можно придумать миллион

Comment: А группировка без использования агрегатных функций - вообще [censored]. Для этого есть DISTINCT.